# Unix Comando Grep manipulacao da saida caso nao encontre resultado

Tags: linux, script, shell, unix

Bom dia!! Estou criando um script e preciso que quando faco um grep em uma linha e nao encontre ela ele me retorne o parametro que procurei!

grep "192.0.0.1 " /arquivo.txt

No arquivo.txt nao tem a string "192.0.0.1 " quero que ele me retorne "192.0.0.1 " para mim salvar em outro arquivo, nao estou conseguindo usa diff por que o padrao em cada linha no arquivo e diferente.

Obrigado

Answer (score 2):

Pessoal consegui resolver esse problema da seguinte forma!

```
grep -v '^#' < arquivo.com.o.que.procuro | while read line2; do

valor=$(grep -c "$line2 " arquivo.onde.estou.procurando)                     

if [ $valor -eq 0 ]; then          
   echo $line2 >> arquivo.onde.vai.salvar.o.que.nao.encontrou                     
   echo $line2 $valor "eh diferente"                            
 fi

done
```